# Can you use a Gradle plugin as a dependency to another Gradle plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, kotlin-native

If I have one Gradle plugin that wants to read and modify the properties of another gradle plugin, I would need the source of the other plugin as a dependency, right? This way I could do `project.pluginManager.getPlugin(PluginClass.class`) and manipulate it's properties. Is it possible to include a gradle plugin as a dependency?

My specific use case is, I wish to make a plugin to detect if kotlin multiplatform plugin is applied and then generate some source files and add them as sources for the various compilations depending on the targets defined.